# Execute calling function further only if Promise returns true in Firebase Cloud function : Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've an HTTPS Cloud Function:

```
export const verifyUser = functions.https.onRequest((req,response) =>{
        if(verifyUserRequest(“xxx”,”yyy”)) console.log(“valid user”)
        else console.log(“invalid user”)
    })


verifyUserRequest(uid: any, userToken: any): Promise<boolean>{
        const firestoreDb = admin.firestore();
        let userRef = firestoreDb.collection('India').doc(uid)
        return userRef.get().then(doc => {
            if(!doc.exists) return false
            else if(doc.get('authToken')===userToken){
                console.log('user token valid');
                return true
            }
            else return false 
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            return false
        })
    }
```

Based on returned value of `verifyUserRequest()` while calling at `export const verifyUser`, I want corresponding log.
But that function is `async` function. How do I implement it in Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

For any function that returns a promise, use `then()` (or async/await syntax) to get the returned value.  This works exactly like the Firestore APIs that return a promise that you're already using now.  This is also standard promise handling JavaScript, which you can do searches to learn about.

```
export const verifyUser = functions.https.onRequest((req,response) =>{
    verifyUserRequest("xxx", "yyy")
    .then(result => {
        if(result) console.log("valid user")
        else console.log("invalid user")
    })
})
```

You should also make your function send a result to the caller so it won't time out.